is it possible to create shadow for inactive thumb in range slider?
my question is quite straightforward: is there any way to set a shadow with a blur around an inactive thumb of range slider? The problem is precisely in the inactive thumb of range slider and what I need is not an elevation or smth like this, but a shadow with a blur around thumb.
I was able to create the desired shadow only for the active thumbs of the slider, but not for the inactive ones, that is, those that the user has not touched yet
The code:
class PriceRangeSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  const PriceRangeSlider({
    Key? key,
    required this.currentRangeValues,
    required this.onChanged,
    required this.minPrice,
    required this.maxPrice,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final RangeValues currentRangeValues;
  final ValueChanged<RangeValues> onChanged;
  final double minPrice;
  final double maxPrice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeColors colors = context.colors;
    final SliderThemeData sliderData = SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
      activeTrackColor: colors.darkText,
      inactiveTrackColor: colors.lightGrey,
      trackHeight: Di.p4,
      thumbColor: colors.contrastWhite,
      thumbShape: CustomThumbShape(),
      overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 0),
    );

    return Padding(
      padding: const Pad(top: Di.p20),
      child: SliderTheme(
        data: sliderData,
        child: RangeSlider(
          values: currentRangeValues,
          min: minPrice,
          max: maxPrice,
          onChanged: onChanged,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomThumbShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size(24.0, 24.0);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
      PaintingContext context,
      Offset offset,
      {required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
        required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
        required bool isDiscrete,
        required TextPainter labelPainter,
        required RenderBox parentBox,
        required Size sizeWithOverflow,
        required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
        required TextDirection textDirection,
        required double textScaleFactor,
        required double value}) {

    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;


    final double outerRadius = 16.0; 
    final double innerRadius = 12.0; 

    final Paint shadowPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final Paint outerPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red 
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0;


    final Paint innerPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black 
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;


    canvas.drawCircle(offset, outerRadius + 6, shadowPaint);
    
    canvas.drawCircle(offset, outerRadius, outerPaint);

    canvas.drawCircle(offset, innerRadius, innerPaint);

    final Offset inactiveOffset = Offset(offset.dx + 20, offset.dy);

    
    final Paint inactiveShadowPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red.withOpacity(0.6) 
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

   
    canvas.drawCircle(inactiveOffset, outerRadius + 45, inactiveShadowPaint); 
    canvas.drawCircle(inactiveOffset, outerRadius, outerPaint);
    
    canvas.drawCircle(inactiveOffset, innerRadius, innerPaint);
  }
}


One thing you first have to understand is that both of the thumbs are painted using the same shape class. Good thing though is that we should be able to detect which thumb we're currently painting
Here's an example
class CustomThumbShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    // Include space for shadow
    return const Size(32.0, 32.0);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center, {
    required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required bool isDiscrete,
    required TextPainter labelPainter,
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required double value,
    required double textScaleFactor,
    required Size sizeWithOverflow,
  }) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;

    // Shadow paint with blur effect
    final shadowPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3)
      ..maskFilter = const MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, 8);

    // Main thumb paint
    final thumbPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    // Draw shadow first
    canvas.drawCircle(center, 12, shadowPaint);
    // Draw thumb on top
    canvas.drawCircle(center, 12, thumbPaint);
  }
}

The key is using MaskFilter.blur in the shadow paint. This creates a proper blurred shadow effect that works for both thumbs. Apply it to your RangeSlider like this:
SliderTheme(
  data: SliderThemeData(
    thumbShape: CustomThumbShape(),
    ...
  ),
  child: RangeSlider(
    ...
  ),
)

Hope this helps
